# How can i customize Wordpress list_users capability?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I am trying to find a way to customize the `list_users` capability in Wordpress,
I have created a new role called `my_admin` and i added some capabilities to it.
The problem is that the `list_users` capability displays all users while i want to display only a group of users according to a user meta field.

Another question about the `edit_users` capability can i limit this capability to edit the users without promoting them, this capability enables editing the users and also promoting them which means that it enables changes to user roles also. Is there any way i can remove this promoting feature from it, can i also select only one input field to be edited and remove other fields?

```
function my_new_service_capabilities() {

    // Get the role object.
    $editor = get_role( 'my_admin' );

    // A list of capabilities to add.
     $addcaps = array(
    'read',
    'edit_posts',
    'list_users', //I need to list users according to a user meta value.
    'edit_users', //I need to enable editing users in only one input field
    'moderate_comments',
    );

    foreach ( $addcaps as $acap ) {

        // Add the capability.
        $editor->add_cap( $acap );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_new_service_capabilities' );
```

Comment: there is a site for WordPress developement questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you →
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

## steps →

1. Retrieve all users.
2. User For each loop.
3. Use meta_query parameter, because WP stores capabilities as json
   string in user_meta.

I am giving you a clue how to do this →

```
 $entire_user_list = get_users();
    $somse_users= array();
    
    foreach($entire_user_list as $user){
    
        if($user->has_cap('specific_capability')){
            $somse_users[] = $user;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: I want to display this in the users section in the admin

Comment: The `list_users` capability when assigned to a user role it enable this user to view all other users in the admin area, I need to customize it to let the user view only a group of users according to user meta field.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved it using the `DOMDocument` class.